# Problems with wowza, dash, ssl, and cors

Tags: cors, wowza, mpeg-dash

I'm trying to stream mpeg video using dash.js and wowza. I configured VHost.xml to stream ssl over port 443 and gave it my keystorepath and keystorepassword.  I used this link https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm to create my jks from letsencrypt certificates.  I created the jks from my fullchain.pem and privKey.pem.  I also enabled CORS in crossdomain.xml.  I can see that SSL streaming and CORS are enabled in the enginemanager ui as well.  Here is how I create the stream using the wowza rest api on port 8087.

```
HTTP POST called : http://ip-address:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/App/streamfiles/96728ede-bda0-4fe7-86e1-724f5ea6237b
Post Response: {"success":true,"message":"","data":null}
HTTP PUT called : http://ip-address:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/streamfiles/96728ede-bda0-4fe7-86e1-724f5ea6237b/actions/connect?connectAppName=App&appInstance=_definst_&mediaCasterType=rtp&vhostName=_defaultVHost_&streamfileName=96728ede-bda0-4fe7-86e1-724f5ea6237b
PUT Response: {"success":true,"message":"Publish stream successfully started [App/_definst_]: mp4:96728ede-bda0-4fe7-86e1-724f5ea6237b.stream","data":null}
```

I've tried these POST and PUT requests with hostname:8087 rather than ip-address:8087 and get the same error.
Then from my js I see this error in the console in chrome.

```
GET https://hostname/App/96728ede-bda0-4fe7-86e1-724f5ea6237b.stream/manifest.mpd 404 (Not Found)
c @ dash.all.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ dash.all.min.js:6
index#/security:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://hostname/App/96728ede-bda0-4fe7-86e1-724f5ea6237b.stream/manifest.mpd. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8090' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or has faced this issue before?

Comment: `https://hostname/App/96728ede-bda0-4fe7-86e1-724f5ea6237b.stream/manifest.mpd` is 404, according to that error message.

So the root cause is, the server isn’t finding the resource at that URL.

Mention of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the message is just because the server isn’t sending that response header in the error response—probably because it’s only configured to send it for non-errors.

So it’s the browser telling your frontend code, *“I can’t give you the response body of the 404 error response, because the server didn’t send it with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`”*.